# Split SQL result into fields and turn them in Columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just got a doubt with a SELECT query.

In my project I have a main table for users and I've created some more tables to split the content, something like this:

tblUser
uid
uname
udateofbirth
uadress

tblPhoneNumber
pid
uid
ptype
pnumber

tblPhoneRelation
uid
pid

I need to SELECT the fields from the user table with the results of the phone table, but the problem is that I need to split the phones into different fields, and my phone number search can return 0 to 4 results for each user.

What I've got is similar to this and gives me the result of the Cell phone (defined in the ptype like 1 to cell phone, 2 for home phone, 3 for commercial phone and 4 for message):

```
SELECT u.uname AS Name, u.udateofbirth AS 'Date of B.', p.pnumber AS 'Cell phone' FROM tblUser AS u JOIN phonerelation ON u.uid = phonerelation.uid JOIN tblPhoneNumber AS p WHERE p.pid = 1 AND p.pid = phonerelation.pid;
```

And my result

Name | Date of B. | Cell phone

But i need to increase to:

Name | Date of B. | Cell phone | Home phone | Commercial phone | Message phone

Sugestions?

Comment: can you please post some tables / data on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
SELECT u.uname AS Name, u.udateofbirth AS 'Date of B.', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 1 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Cell phone',
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 2 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Home phone', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 3 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Commercial phone',  
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.ptype = 4 THEN p.pnumber END) AS 'Message phone' 
FROM tblUser AS u 
JOIN phonerelation ON u.uid = phonerelation.uid 
JOIN tblPhoneNumber AS p ON p.pid = phonerelation.pid
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Ty vm por the help, but I'm trying to use this code in another place to create a user phone list and split into fields on Lazarus (Delphi), I've tryied to edit it a little bit but I'm getting more then one line in my result list. What i need to cut when I'm selecting only the phone numbers, the user is stored inside a var so I dont need a research on users table for id comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it is inappropriate to have many-to-many between `users` and `phones`.  Instead have simply 1 user -to- many phones.

Then something like

```
CREATE TABLE Phones (
        uid ...,
        type ENUM('cell', 'home', ...),
        pnumber VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ascii,
    PRIMARY KEY(uid, type, pnumber)
);

SELECT u.uname, ...
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(p.type, ': ', p.number) SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Phone(s)'
    FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN Phones p USING(uid)
    GROUP BY uid
```

With `PRIMARY KEY(uid, type)`, instead, it would limit each user to a single Cell numbers for a single user.  (This might be a desirable feature.)